# Does wearing a Divine Helm actually affect its relative spirit?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Divine Helms description states (this is the Rito one):

> A helm worn by a warrior who protected the Rito in a time beyond memory. It's said to **deepen the bond** with the Rito when worn by a Hylian."

Fun fact, when you wear the helm the relative spirit wears the mask, too.

[image: Goron spirit wearing Link's helm]

This is cool, but what does "deepen the bond" actually mean? Does this do anything or is it just aesthetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [Reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/zelda/comments/13iu83v/totk_if_you_wear_a_divine_beast_helm_with_the/):

> I did some rough testing, and wearing the divine helm appears to give the sage a ~50% damage boost in normal combat. It stacks with the other sage upgrade. It doesn't appear to have any effect on the sage ability.